# React Binding syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am making a simple doodle/drawing app for my own tutorial. As a simple first step, I wanted to provide a way for them select the `pen color` by entering something like `Red`, `Green`, or `#880000` (hex code).

This is how I implemented it,  is there a simpler/neater way?

**NOTE:** The `state` variable is defined in the constructor and includes `penColor` and a few other properties.

```
<div className='penControls'>
    <div>Pen Color 
        <div className='colorPicker' >
            <input type="text" id="penColor" name='penColor' defaultValue={this.state.penColor}
                onChange={
                     (ev) => {
                         this.state.penColor = document.getElementById('penColor').value;
                         this.setState(this.state);
                     }
                }
                className="penColorPicker mx-4" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with React you should avoid the use document API, so there's no need of `document.getElementById`, use `event.target.value` that is sent in the `event` object when calling `onChange`

Also, never assign a value to your state directly like this

```
this.state.foo = 'bar';
```

Use `setState`function for this:

```
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' })
```

That'll dispatch all the component life cycle related to re-rendering in a safe way

Finally, try with the following code...

```
<div className='penControls'>
    <div>Pen Color 
        <div className='colorPicker' >
            <input type="text" id="penColor" name='penColor' defaultValue={this.state.penColor}
                onChange={
                     (ev) => {
                         const newPenColor = event.target.value;
                         this.setState({ penColor: newPenColor });
                     }
                }
                className="penColorPicker mx-4" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this `this.setState({ foo: 'bar' })` cause some data-loss if there are other properties on the state object in the constructor??? thank you!

Comment: No, it doesn't, `setState`funcion will change the value for key-object pair that you call it with. E.g. `state.a = 0`and `state.b = 0`, if you call `this.setState({ a: 1 })`and look for the state it should be now `state.a = 1`and `state.b = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS tries to solve the exact problem you are facing of reading from DOM and updating the state. But we need to update the state in React way.

```
    <div className='penControls'>
<div>Pen Color 
    <div className='colorPicker' >
        <input type="text" id="penColor" name='penColor' defaultValue={this.state.penColor}
            onChange={
                 (ev) => {

                     let newPenColor = this.state.penColor
                     this.setState({ penColor: newPenColor });
                 }
            }
            className="penColorPicker mx-4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[React State Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: It doesn't look that any different that the code i wrote.  what am I missing?  also, this code would lose the other values I have in the `state`   I have other values like `penSize` etc.

Comment: no, merging the new value to the old state is done internally by React.